# Groking UNIX file timestamps

Tags: find, ls, timestamps

The `find` manual lists several different file timestamps:

```
access time:  (amin, anewer)
changed time: (cmin, cnewer)
last modified time: (mmin)
```

This is the output from: **ls -lrt *.log**

Which timestamp is displayed?

How can I get the other timestamp information?

```
-rwxr-xr-x 0 xr kchd  71679 Feb 16  2017 sys_rm2888959.log
-rwxr-xr-x 0 xr kchd 104974 Feb 16  2017 sys_rm2888982.log
-rwxr-xr-x 0 xr kchd 107627 Feb 16  2017 sys_rm2888998.log
-rwxr-xr-x 0 xr kchd 110731 Apr 10 07:11 sys_rm2888896.log
-rwxr-xr-x 0 xr kchd 110022 Apr 18 08:22 sys_rm2888135.log
-rwxr-xr-x 0 xr kchd 102135 May 16 04:35 sys_rm2888749.log
-rwxr-xr-x 0 xr kchd 107374 May 22 02:17 sys_rm2888075.log
-rwxr-xr-x 0 xr kchd   9170 Jun  5 09:20 sys_rm2888328.log
-rwxr-xr-x 0 xr kchd 110097 Jun 12 09:39 sys_rm2888264.log
-rwxr-xr-x 0 xr kchd 109516 Jul 17 01:15 sys_rm2888542.log
-rwxr-xr-x 0 xr kchd 100893 Jul 17 03:18 sys_rm2888567.log
-rwxr-xr-x 0 xr kchd 101035 Aug 21 05:10 sys_rm2888543.log
-rwxr-xr-x 0 xr kchd 110879 Aug 28 07:18 sys_rm2888859.log
```

Comment: See `man ls`, `-u` for access time, `-c` for change status time.

Comment: Also `stat` to get each time and some more info for a file.

Answer (score 0):

- `ls -l` shows the "last modified" timestamp by default.
- To see the "last accessed" timestamp, use `ls -l -u`.
- To see the "last change" timestamp ("time of last modification of the file status information"), use `ls -l -c`.

Your command,

```
ls -lrt *.log
```

Would list the all names in the current directory matching the pattern `*.log`, sorting the output on the last modified timestamp as the primary key, and using the filename as the secondary key (for the cases where two or more files have the same timestamp). The sorting will be done in order of most recently modified last (reverse of the default).